# Send string to next page url using formaction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that uses jquery for input options in a separate file

```
// JavaScript Document
var regExp = /\s/g;

var model = submodel = variant = capacity = '';

var formAction = 'http://google.com/';

//Prepare various Select Elements for OTHER
//Please use alphanumaric(a-z,A-Z,0-9) for keys 
//You can use special characters like (+, &, -, _, space etc.) for values
var AppleiPhone     =   {
                        //Keys                  //Values
                        "Other"                 : "Other",
                    };
```

I want to send a string to the next page and I have a code that I use but I can't get it to work using form action. Here's the code.

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
  jQuery('#standard').click(function(){
       var url=$(location).attr('href');
       var pieces = url.split("?");
       var newurl=jQuery("#standard").attr('data-target')+'?'+pieces[1]+'/standard-shipping';
       location.href=newurl;
   }); 

});
```

The problem is that the string script is calling on data-target and I need to know if there's any way to call on 'formaction' to make the string send the the next page url.

Comment: You can find the parent form and get its action attribute...

Comment: So you want to grab something on the current URL, and append it to the data you are sending to a form?

Comment: @IvoPereira Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

I would not follow @vogomatrix solution as you could have many forms in the page, and that would be a too general solution.

I would specify an ID on the form, and do something like this:

```
var pieces = url.split("?");

("#submit_button").click(function(){   
    var url=$(location).attr('href'),
        form = $('#form'), // Save form element
        oldAction = form.attr('action'); // Save form old action

    // Set new action
    form.attr('action', oldAction + '?' + pieces[1]);
});
```

In your example you use this:

```
location.href=newurl;
```

Take in mind that changing the href of the user and redirecting him does not get the form data with the client, as you are not POSTing the data to a form.

Comment: You add an ID to the form on the HTML.

Comment: My form has an id of: id='grid-quiz' and I applied that changing #form to #grid-quiz to no luck.

This is an example of my separate query file:

`function submitValue1(isCapacity)
{
 /* get all selected values */
 var iPodModelValue    = $('#iPodModel').val();
 var iPodVarientValue   = $('#iPodVarient').val();
 
 var url = formAction+'?q1='+iPodModelValue+"&q2="+iPodVarientValue+"&q3="+iPodCapacityValue;
 location.href = url;
}`

Comment: Check the edit I've made some while ago. You cannot use location.href and expect receiving data from POST in the action page of the form. You need to post the data, just submit the form using a <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

Comment: Doing that would cause my entire form to be inactive. Using the code I displayed above generates links based on select options that are chosen. Is there a work-around for a situation like this?

Comment: Is there anything I can do sir?

Comment: I'm sorry sir, but I did not understand. Isn't what you are looking: "grab something on the current URL, and append it to the data you are sending to a form"?